# How to add Publisher by certificate?

Tags: java, certificate, digital-signature

I want to show the warning box when I run my Java application. Just like this[image]

How to add the certificate for showing Publisher when running my Java application?
Please show the way.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your Java application, or someone elses?

If it is yours, then the primary problem is that you are using an expired certificate.  You will need to go back to your certificate provider and renew it.  This will most likely involve paying a new fee.

Once you got the new certificate, you will need to put it in the right place for the JAR file signer to find it.  We can't tell you where that is, but your build scripts may contain some clues.

Please read the following tutorial page for general information on how to sign a JAR file:

- Signing JAR Files  - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html

---

> I wanna show just like this box for my java application.

That page is displayed by the application launcher, not by the application.  And if the application is properly signed, you won't see the page.  The page is warning the user that something bad could be about to happen!!!  (In this case, that the JAR is signed using a certificate that should no longer be trusted ... since it has expired.)

If you are not seeing a window like that and your application is not signed, it is because the launcher you are using does not require a signed JAR.

What launcher are you actually using?

> I have a new certificate but I don't know how to add my certificate in the java application. I've no experience of adding certificate to the java application. Please, if you don't mind show me step by step functions.

Please read the tutorial that I linked to above.

Comment: No, it's not my java application. I wanna show just like this box for my java application. I have a new certificate but I don't know how to add my certificate in the java application. I've no experience of adding certificate to the java application. Please, if you don't mind show me step by step functions. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how to use it. I explain how to work my application. I wrote a java program using eclipse and I exported jar by using fat jar exporter. And then I exported exe by using kickstart application. Where step to add my certificate and what launcher should I use? I didn't know how to sign the jar file. Please explain me. I'm really sorry for my bad.

Comment: @shariphwar - Have you read the tutorial?  Have you tried signing the JAR file the way that the tutorial describes?   If you don't understand what JAR signing is about, read the previous section of the tutorial - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/intro.html